# MS-Word VBA Error : Text box controls Issue

Tags: windows, vba, ms-office, ms-word

Please refer to the attached error message as while executing this word macro I am getting this:

> The program used to create this object is forms. that program is either not installed on your computer or it is not responding. To edit this object, install forms or ensure that any dialog boxes in the forms are closed

[image]

Kindly let me know what could be the issue in it.

Comment: "while executing this word macro" - did you forget to include your code?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025036

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply:) No....code is there

Answer (score 0):

This error message might be related to a missing Office update. Please make sure that your Office installation is fully patched (or that at least the update mentioned in the below article is installed).

For a detailed explanation check this article on Microsoft's support website:

> **["Cannot insert object" error in an ActiveX custom Office solution after you install the MS14-082 security update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025036)**